# What's the AWS SDK version that's compatible with Spring Boot 2.7.9?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-sdk

What's the AWS SDK version that's compatible with Spring Boot 2.7.9?
Is there some compatibility matrix where I can know which version of each one I should use?

Thanks.

Comment: Q: Why do you think there might be any "compatilibity issues"?  Outside of "minimum Java" (for example, I doubt you could use Java 1.2 with most contemporary libraries)? Why not just use the latest/greatest AWS SDK in your Sprint Boot app?  There *shouldn't* be any strict dependency between Spring Boot version and AWS SDK version, should there?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like version 2 of the AWS SDK would be supported for Java.

Relevant links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/version-support-matrix.html

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2

https://awspring.io/learn/introduction/#versions